# Detect regularity in arrival times

Tags: time-series, hypothesis-testing, mathematical-statistics, signal-processing, signal-detection

I am working with series of arrival times. My typical dataset is made of 20-100 samples.

I would like to detect regularity in the arrival time.
By regularity, I mean that the inter-arrival times may be constant or increase (decrease) linearly with time for example.
My "alternative" hypothesis is that the arrival times are random (e.g. from a Poisson process, but I don't really know this).

I guess that there are a bunch of randomness tests for example, but I would prefer to have an "indicator of randomness" rather than a strict binary result.

How would you do this or what test would you recommend ?

Merci à tous pour votre aide,

Clément